# First html page opens but clicking any link within that page causes crash the app

Tags: android, android-webview

My `WebView` open a local `html` file when the app starts. It opens perfectly but any link within that page causes a crash of the app when clicked.

On the bug report, it says,

`signal 6 (SIGABRT), code-6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr ----- Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext:cc:475] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewLocalRef called with pending exception adroid.os.FileUriExposedException: file///android_asset/page2.html exposed beyond app through Intget.getData()`

Similar problems have been addressed so many times before but even after digging different solutions for some time, I haven't been able to solve the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

My `MainActivity.java` page:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Load WebView with HTML from Assets folder
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack())
            myWebView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.html">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.rimikri.PRx.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says: "This exposure is discouraged since the receiving app may not have access to the shared path. For example, the receiving app may not have requested the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime permission, or the platform may be sharing the Uri across user profile boundaries." (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html)

Try to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html